# Unable to add multiple url variables inside <td> tag in php

Tags: php, html-table, href

I am trying to show one table row data inside php's  tag with some url variables so that when the url is clicked it should open a new page with the 2 url variables passed. But the table data should show the first url variable in assigned but the new page should show both the url variables assigned.

The 2nd variable user will be assigned the next variable read which is incremented by 1 to get the value.

```
for ($line=0;$line<count($data);$line++)
{
    if($line == 0)
    {
        echo "<td><a target=_blank href=somepage.php?hostname=".$data[$line]."&user= >".$data[$line + 1]."</a></td>";
            }
```

....
....

When I use the above code, the table data show the 2nd variable value hyperlinked and on click it is opening another new page with the url as-
somepage.php?hostname=my_hostname&user=

So the new page is not getting the 2nd variable value populated after clicked.

I tried many things but it did not solve the issue completely.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your attributes (i.e. href) are in quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add **single quotes** to your href tags but make sure they are different from your string enclosures.

```
echo "<td><a target=_blank href='somepage.php?hostname=".$data[$line]."&user=".$data[$line + 1]."'>".$data[$line + 1]."</a></td>";
```

With the second variable you had your closing tags before the variable.

Comment: now the href is opening the new page with both variables assigned. however my table row data shows the 2nd variable value as hyperlink which I want the first variable to show as hyperlink and on click it should show the new page with both variables. sorry if I missed to describe this part. thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it resolved what I wanted. The right code for my expectation is -
echo "<td><a target=_blank href='somepage.php?hostname=".$data[$line]."&user=".$data[$line + 1]."'>".$data[$line]."</a></td>";